# Tikzpicture horizontal curly brace

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, draw, axis

[image]

I got the axis. I did it with `\begin{tikzpicture}`.
How do I draw this curly brace?

Comment: can you please add a code snippet of what you tried to do so far?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick,-{latex}] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[below]{$x$};
\foreach \x/\l in {1/-r,3/{},5/+r}
  \draw (\x,3pt) -- (\x,-3pt) node[below]{$x_0\l$};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt,mirror,raise=4ex}]
  (1,0) -- (5,0) node[midway,yshift=-3em]{Konvergenzbereich};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (4.5,0) node[below left]{$x$};
\foreach \X/\Y in {1/-r,2/{\vphantom{-r}},3/+r}
{ \draw (\X,0.15) -- (\X,-0.15) node[below] (X-\X){$x_0{\Y}$};}
\path[draw,decorate,decoration=brace] (X-3.south east) -- (X-1.south west)
node[midway,below,font=\small\sffamily]{Konvergenzbereich};
\begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[below left]{$x$};
\foreach \X/\Y in {1/-r,3/{\vphantom{-r}},5/+r}
{ \draw (\X,0.15) -- (\X,-0.15) node[below] (X-\X){$x_0{\Y}$};}
\path[draw,decorate,decoration=brace] (X-5.south) -- (X-1.south)
node[midway,below,font=\small\sffamily]{Konvergenzbereich};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]